# Override entrypoint in Codeship service's image

Tags: docker, codeship

I'm working with a multi-stage image which builds and tests the service in the build process and it works fine with the push steps. The only problem is that I don't want to push the image every time a build of the `feature` branch is sent to Codeship, so I have this in my `codeship-steps.yaml`:

```
 - name: Build API
    type: serial
    steps:
    - name: Build API image
      tag: ^(feature)
      service: api
      command: true
    - name: Push staging API image
      tag: ^(develop)
      type: push
      service: api
      image_name: gcr.io/project/api
      image_tag: "{{.CommitID}}"
      registry: https://gcr.io
      dockercfg_service: staging-gcr
    - name: Push production API image
      tag: ^(master)
      type: push
      service: api
      image_name: gcr.io/project/api
      image_tag: "{{.CommitID}}"
      registry: https://gcr.io
      dockercfg_service: production-gcr
```

and this in `codeship-services.yaml`:

```
api:
  build:
    image: singularities/codeship-api
    dockerfile: api/Dockerfile
```

Everything should work fine, but the `Build API image` step fails because it try to run the service like `docker run`. Is there any way to override the entrypoint or tell Codeship to only build the image like `docker build`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of entrypoint scripts, my suggestion would be to create an argument that allows the script to exit successfully.

If you'd like, you can send your steps/services/Dockerfile(s)/entrypoint script to support@codeship.com and we will take a closer look.